# Subclass method doesn't override its super generic method

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, groovy, overriding

I have a generic method in the super class. I want to override this based on entity type in subclasses. These codes are written in groovy language.

```
 protected T fromEntity(E entity) {
     return entity
 }
```

I want to override this method in my subclass. This is supposed to be one of the overridden methods:

```
@Override
protected FactorInfo fromEntity(Factor f) {
    // extract and return FactorInfo from f
    return new FactorInfo()
}
```

But my IDE says:

> Method does not override method from its super class.

Why this method doesn't override the super method?

Comment: Your override only provides an implementation for one specific combination of `T` and `E` - it needs to work for all of them.

Comment: Please add: Groovy version, the class and subclass so we can see how the generics are defined; and what IDE is this and is this IDE the only one complaining (as in: does to compile and run just fine)?